Using Terraform azurerm_subnet to create a subnet in an existing azure VNet giving IP overlap error
Requirement : I am trying to create a Azure Subnet  into an existing VNet. Terraform IAC.
Issue : I am unable to dynamically get the available IP ranges in the VNet's address space and assign one available IP to Subnet's address_prefixes variable.
Question : Is there any way to first get the available IP ranges in a VNet address space and then assign one of them to SubNet's address prefixes.
I tried using [cidrsubnet(<VNet's Address Space>, ,netnum, <no. of subents to be created>)
module "subnet"{
    source = "./modules/sub-net"
    name =  "${var.environment}${replace(var.servicename,"-","")}Subnet"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
    virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name
    address_prefixes= cidrsubnet(data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.address_space[0], 4, 2)]
    network_security_group_id = "${var.network_security_group_id}"
    route_table_id = "${var.route_table_id}
}

But this gives an IP that is already in use, it does not validates the availability of the IP and so terraform apply throws an IP overlap error.
Last option used is to harcode the available IP address as value to address_prefixes but this is not a good standard to follow especially if we are creating for multiple environments and so on.
module "subnet"{
    source = "./modules/sub-net"
    name =  "${var.environment}${replace(var.servicename,"-","")}Subnet"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
    virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name
    address_prefixes = ["1XX.20.1XX.2XX/28"]
    network_security_group_id = "${var.network_security_group_id}"
    route_table_id = "${var.route_table_id}"
   
}


Can you please share the error info you got when you tried CIDRSubnet @AmanKumar

You can use Terraform CIDR Subnets module to split your vnet into subnets - more details here.
The only downside is you will have to define all your subnets before you actually create any of your resource. In a way, this is a good practice to define networking first.
